# Getting Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed error in nestjs in my upload module that is using FileInterceptor

Tags: typescript, nestjs

- Locally : Everything is working fine
- On deployment site ex Render and Railway the error is coming.

I have commented some code lines because am trying to deduce the fix for this, am new to nestjs so i don't know exactly where this error is coming from.

**Here is my Upload controller code:**

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Delete,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  MaxFileSizeValidator,
  ParseFilePipe,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { FileTypeInterceptor } from './Interceptors/FileTypeInterceptor';
import { UploadService } from './upload.service';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';

@Controller('file')
export class UploadController {
  constructor(private readonly uploadService: UploadService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './uploadedFiles/avatars',
      }),
    }),
    FileTypeInterceptor,
  )
  async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: 10000000 })],
      }),
    )
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    try {
      const uploadedFile = file;
      const imageUrl = await this.uploadService.uploadFile(uploadedFile);

      // Handle the success case and send a custom response
      return {
        data: {
          url: imageUrl,
        },
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        statusCode: 200,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // Handle errors and send a custom error response
      return {
        data: {},
        message: `${error}`,
        statusCode: 500,
      };
    }
  }

  // @Delete('delete')
  // async deleteFile(@Body('fileName') fileName: string) {
  //   try {
  //     if (!fileName) {
  //       throw new HttpException(
  //         'Provide a filename to delete',
  //         HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
  //       );
  //     }

  //     // Call the deleteFile function from your service to delete the file
  //     await this.uploadService.deleteFile(fileName);

  //     // Send a success response
  //     return { message: 'File deleted successfully' };
  //   } catch (error) {
  //     console.error('Error deleting file:', error);
  //     throw new HttpException(
  //       'Failed to delete file',
  //       HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
  //     );
  //   }
  // }
}
```

**Here is the service file for this Upload module**

On commenting imports from @aws-sdk/client-s3 it is working fine.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
// import {
//   S3Client,
//   PutObjectCommand,
//   DeleteObjectCommand,
// } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  // private readonly s3Client = new S3Client({
  //   credentials: {
  //     accessKeyId: this.configService.get('accessKey'),
  //     secretAccessKey: this.configService.get('secretAccessKey'),
  //   },
  //   region: this.configService.get('bucketRegion'),
  // });
  generateUniqueFileName(originalName: string) {
    const uniqueString = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    const extension = originalName.split('.').pop();
    return `${uniqueString}.${extension}`;
  }

  async uploadFile(uploadedFile: Express.Multer.File) {
    try {
      const uniqueFileName = this.generateUniqueFileName(
        uploadedFile.originalname,
      );
      // const uploadParams = {
      //   Bucket: this.configService.get('bucketName'),
      //   Key: uniqueFileName,
      //   Body: uploadedFile.buffer,
      //   ContentType: uploadedFile.mimetype,
      // };
      // const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams);
      // await this.s3Client.send(uploadCommand);
      // const imageUrl = `https://${this.configService.get(
      //   'bucketName',
      // )}.s3.${this.configService.get(
      //   'bucketRegion',
      // )}.amazonaws.com/${uniqueFileName}`;
      const imageUrl = 'hahah';
      return imageUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error('Problem in uploading the image');
    }
  }

  async deleteFile(fileName: string) {
    try {
      const deleteParams = {
        Bucket: this.configService.get('bucketName'),
        Key: fileName,
      };
      // const deleteCommand = new DeleteObjectCommand(deleteParams);
      // await this.s3Client.send(deleteCommand);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error deleting file:', error);
      throw new Error('Problem in deleting the file');
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is my Custom Interceptor checking the correct file type**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FileTypeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    if (!request || !request.body || !request.body.type) {
      // If no request or no 'type' attribute in the request body, return an error response
      throw new HttpException(
        'Missing or invalid "type" attribute in request body',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }

    // Determine the valid file types based on the 'type' attribute in the form data
    const validFileTypes: string[] = this.getValidFileTypes(request.body.type);

    const uploadedFile = request.file; // Assuming you're using multer for file upload

    if (!uploadedFile || !validFileTypes.includes(uploadedFile.mimetype)) {
      // If no uploaded file or invalid file type, return an error response
      throw new HttpException('Invalid file type', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // If the file type is valid, proceed with the request
    return next.handle();
  }

  private getValidFileTypes(requestType: string): string[] {
    // Define valid file types based on the 'type' attribute in the request
    switch (requestType) {
      case 'image':
        return ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']; // Define valid image types
      case 'video':
        return ['video/mp4', 'video/mpeg']; // Define valid video types
      default:
        return []; // Add other valid types as needed
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is my upload module file**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadService } from './upload.service';
import { UploadController } from './upload.controller';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  controllers: [UploadController],
  providers: [UploadService],
})
export class UploadModule {}
```

**Error image:**

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]